# Are L-shaped and T-shaped Magsafe 1 interchangeable?

Tags: macbook-pro, charging, power, repair, magsafe

I want to buy replacement Magsafe 1 cable for my MBP 17" Late 2011, and they are available in two options — L-shaped and T-shaped. My computer was shipped with L-shaped connector, however I want to swap it for T-shaped, as I find it more convenient.

So, will it fit? Are there current restrictions on T-shaped connectors, e.g. won't they overheat when powering 85W MBP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short **no, there's no problem**.

Apple changed the "old" T-models with new L-models.

However, they are exactly the same and I've been using a 85Watt MagSafe charger for years now as it charges much faster.
Just do it, and nothing will change, except if you go from 45/60 watt to 85 (it will load faster :)). It's just a new look, the connectors are exactly the same.

Comment: My charger is already 85W, I just want to change connector from L (which is broken, so it should be changed anyway) to T-shaped.

Comment: That's just OK. Go ahead! I've done the same, except I came from 60Watt. I've just added that detail that might help others with 45 or 60 watt in the future asking the same question.

Answer (score 1):

Should't be a problem. The interface with the computer is the same. There shouldn't be any issues with overheating or anything. I used the power brick that came with my MacBook Air 11 to power a MacBook Pro 15 all day long while I am working and I haven't had any issues except it takes a bit longer to charge.

Comment: Shouldn't assumes you don't know. It's a fact it will work as it's only a change in design.

Comment: Using a higher rater supply for a lower rated device is safe.  What you are doing, using a lower rated supply on a higher rated device is not safe, and you are pushing your power supply adapter past its rated capacity.  it will take longer to charge, but it also stands at risk of overheating if you run the machine at full tilt for a long period of time.  The likely result is shortening the life of the unit.  It will certainly run hotter, although over volt protection etc will hopefully prevent it from combusting.